# How to open existing scripts in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

How to view or open an existing shell script in unix? After viewing the contents how to close the file without modifying its content. Is there a way to view the file in notepad?

Comment: A script is just a text file. Use any text editor you like. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

### To open the file

Use vi: `vi script.sh`

- Quit without saving: Escape -> Type `:q` -> Enter
- Save and quit: Escape -> Type `:wq` -> Enter

### To view the content without opening

Use cat: `cat script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

To view the content of the script file:

```
cat your_script_file.bash
```

To open it in a text editor, it depends on your distribution but it could be: `mousepad`, `gedit`, `kedit`, etc. for the graphical editor, or `vi`, `emacs`, `nano` etc. for the CLI text editors.